# NGRX reducer function returns 2 objects

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I have created a reducer function with the help from an online course, but it is not working completly as intended for me.

[image]

This is my console window that is given after I press 3 vehicles in my list. The blue numbers is the ID, and it fires the second I press the object in the list.

1. First I press vehicle "1075" with ID 93.
2. After that I press vehicle "1072" with ID 92.
3. Finally I press vehicle "1067" with ID 91.

Right now it first returns the "previous" object", which is an empty array the first time I press it, and then after a few seconds it returns the object I pressed.

My code looks like this:

```
// initial state
export const initialState: VehicleDetailState = {
  entities: [],
  loaded: false,
  loading: false
};


// my reducer


 export function reducer(
      state = initialState,
      action: fromVehicleDetail.VehicleDetailAction
    ): any {
      switch (action.type) {
        case fromVehicleDetail.LOAD_VEHICLEDETAIL_SUCCESS: {
          const vehicledetail = action.payload;
          const entities = vehicledetail;
          return {
            entities
          };
        }
      }
      return state;
    }
```

I have tried to return something different in my "LOAD_VEHICLEDETAIL" case, but an error is returned whenever I try to do that, comming from this part of the code:

```
// my listcomponent 
onClick() {

this.store.select(fromStore.getAllVehicleDetail).subscribe(data => {
      this.vehicleDetail = data;
      console.log(this.vehicleDetail);

      if (this.vehicleDetail.position) {
        this.setMap();
        this.setMarkers();
        return;
      }
      this.failSetMap();
      this.setMarkers();
    });
    this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.LoadVehicleDetail());
  }

}
```

(The console.log(this.vehicleDetail) is what is being logged in the console window by the way).

where the error is

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined

What can I do to only return the object that I have most recently pressed on in my list?

Comment: You subscribe on click. That means, your observer is triggered at the beginning and every time the store changes. You should not subscribe on click. Subscribe on init and dispatch on click.

Comment: Thank you so much @ThomasSablik
One benefit with subscribing was that it was useful for setting my map. If I try to use my "this.setMarkers()" function outside a .subscribe() it will not do anything since the position is undefined during the first second after I clicked the item. Is there any way I can fix this so the map zooms in to the correct place whenever the data from my web api is delivered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You subscribe on click. That means, your observer is triggered at the beginning and every time the store changes. You should not subscribe on click. Subscribe on init and dispatch on click.

```
onInit() {

  this.store.select(fromStore.getAllVehicleDetail).subscribe(data => {
      this.vehicleDetail = data;
      console.log(this.vehicleDetail);

      if (this.vehicleDetail.position) {
        this.setMap();
        this.setMarkers();
        return;
      }
      this.failSetMap();
      this.setMarkers();
    });
  }
}

onClick() {
  this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.LoadVehicleDetail());
}
```

In this snippet the observer subscribes on init. Every time the store changes, the observer is triggered. A new vehicle is added on click. After a click a new vehicle is created and added to the store. Then the store is changed and the observer is triggered.

Comment: Thank you so much!